"TransactionExpiredBlockheightExceededError: Signature XXX has expired: block height exceeded" when confirming successful transaction
When attempting to use confirmTransaction using the BlockheightBasedTransactionConfirmationStrategy, the call takes a very long time then errors out with "TransactionExpiredBlockheightExceededError: Signature XXXX has expired: block height exceeded."
const latestBlockHash = await connection.getLatestBlockhash();
const transaction = signTransaction(wallet, swapResponse.swapTransaction);
const txId = await executeTransaction(connection, env, transaction, latestBlockHash);
    

const signTransaction = (wallet: Keypair, swapTransaction: string): VersionedTransaction => {
  // deserialize the transaction
  const swapTransactionBuf = Buffer.from(swapTransaction, 'base64');
  const transaction = VersionedTransaction.deserialize(swapTransactionBuf);

  // sign the transaction
  transaction.sign([wallet]);
  console.log(`transaction: ${JSON.stringify(transaction, null, 2)}`);
  return transaction;
}

const executeTransaction = async (connection: Connection, env: Env, transaction: VersionedTransaction, {blockhash,lastValidBlockHeight}: Readonly<{
  blockhash: string;
  lastValidBlockHeight: number;
}>): Promise<TransactionSignature> => {
  // Execute the transaction
  const rawTransaction = transaction.serialize();
  const signature = await connection.sendRawTransaction(rawTransaction, {
    skipPreflight: true,
    maxRetries: 10,

  });
  console.log(`signature: (${signature})`);
  const confirmStrategy: BlockheightBasedTransactionConfirmationStrategy = {
      blockhash,
      lastValidBlockHeight,
      signature
  }
  try{
    const confirmTransactionResult = await connection.confirmTransaction(confirmStrategy, 'confirmed');
    console.log(`confirmTransactionResult: ${JSON.stringify(confirmTransactionResult, null, 2)}`);
  } catch(e) {
    let txResult = await connection.getTransaction(signature, {
      commitment: 'confirmed', 
      maxSupportedTransactionVersion: 1
    });
    if(!txResult){
      throw new Error(`Transaction failed to confirm: ${JSON.stringify(e, null, 2)}`);
    }
  }
  return signature;
}

The transaction will generally succeed as getTransaction returns a confirmed transaction. What am I doing wrong here? I tried getLatestBlockhash() at various points before confirmation. Any way to do this without using the nonce confirmation strategy?

txId = await executeTransaction(connection, env, transaction, {lastValidBlockHeight: swapResponse.lastValidBlockHeight, blockhash: transaction.message.recentBlockhash});
Also tried using the blockhash and lastValidBlockHeight from the jupiter swap response.

Does this answer your question? How can I analyze the reason for frequent BlockHeightExceeded errors?

Somewhat. The article on solana.com that explains transaction handling isn't even using confirmTransaction. My guess is that network congestion is so bad that not even the normal mechanisms for transaction confirmation are working properly.
